# minimum operations to make array left part equal to right part

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an even length array, [a1, a2,....,an], a beautiful array is an array where a[i] == a[i + n / 2] for 0<= i < n / 2. define an operation as change all array elements equal to value x to value y. what's the minimum operations required to make a given array beautiful? all elements are in range [1, 100000]. If simply return unmatch array pairs (ignore order) in left and right part of array, it will return wrong results in some cases such as [1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 5, 5, 2], unmatched pairs are (1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 5), but when change 2 -> 5, than (1, 2) and (1, 5) become the same. so what's the correct method to solve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the issue you are facing? Post your code here.

Comment: @user7444051 I used the method mentioned above, but it will return wrong result in some cases. then I didn't know how to solve it....

Answer (score 0):

It is a graph question.
For every pair(a[i], a[i+n/2]) where a[i]!=a[i+n/2], add an undirected edge between the two nodes.
Note that you shouldn't add multiple edges between 2 numbers.
Now you essentially need to remove all the edges in the graph by performing some operations. The final answer is the number of operations.
In each operation, you remove an edge. After removing an edge between two vertices, combine the vertices and rearrange their edges.